# Sort list to ease construction of binary tree

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures, language-agnostic, binary-tree

I have a set of items that are supposed to for a balanced binary tree. Each item is of the form `(data,parent)`, `data` being the useful information and `parent` being the index of the parent node in the binary tree.

Nodes in the tree are numbered left-to-right, row-by-row, like this:

```
           1
       ___/ \___
      /         \
     2           3
   _/\_        _/\_
  4    5      6    7
```

These elements come stored in a linked list. How should I order this list such that it's easier for me to build the tree? Each parent node will be referenced (by index) by exactly two child nodes; if I sort these by parent index, the sorting must be stable.

Comment: What do you mean by "to build the tree"? You already have it - in the (strange) format you specified.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev I need it as an actual tree, not as a list that can be viewed as a tree.

Comment: A binary tree implemented with a linked list? The underlaying linked list will negate the advantage of the binary tree.

Comment: @Gumbo It comes as a linked list that "defines" a tree. From this list I need to build the actual tree.

Comment: what does the list contains? the `(data,parent)` information? only the data? Also: `Each parent node will be referenced (by index) by exactly two child nodes` - Is the tree [complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Types_of_binary_trees)? Or we don't know? Do you need to re-create the exact same tree? (with the exact same structure?)

Comment: @amit The list contains `(data,parent)` and the tree is complete.

Comment: @PaulManta And do we have any information on the initial list order? I mean, in your example, how can a tree with `2` as right son of `1`, and `3` as left son of `1` be distinguished from the correct solution? With just the `parent` field - it is not enough? **Please provide input sample for your example**, it will help us understand it better.

Comment: @amit The initial list can be ordered in any way. The only guarantee is that the relative order between two nodes with the same parent will be left-node-first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort the list in any [stable sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability), according to the `parent` field, in increasing order.

The result will be a list like that:

```
[(d_1,nil), (d_2,1), (d_3,1) , (d_4,2), (d_5,2), ...(d_i,x), (d_i+1,x) ]
     ^ 
   the root has no parent...
```

Note that in this list, since we used a stable sort - for each two pairs `(d_i,x), (d_i+1,x)` in the sorted list, `d_i` is the left leaf!

Now, you can populate the tree in [breadth-first traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Breadth-first_traversal),

Since it is homework - I still want you to make sure you understand everything by your own. So I do not want to "feed answer". If you have any *specific* question, please comment - and I will try to edit and explain the relevant parts with more details.

**Bonus**: The result of this organization is very common way to implement a **[binary heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap)** structure, which is a complete binary tree, but for performance, we usually store it as an array, which is very similar to the output generated by this approach.

Comment: Thank you, I understand. :) While I was replying to your comments I realised that sorting by parent index is actually the solution I needed.

Comment: @PaulManta: I am happy to hear that you manage to get it by your own! Just note that is is important to use a stable sort, and not any sort- or the answer will be wrong!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I understand what exactly are you trying to achieve. You have to write the function that inserts items in the tree. The red-black tree, for example, has the same complexity for insertions, O(log n), no matter how the input data is sorted. Is there a specific implementation that you have to use or a specific speed target that you must reach for inserts?

PS: Sounds like a homework to me :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a binary tree that allows you to go from a leaf node to its ancestors, using an array.

Usually sorting a list before putting it into a binary tree causes an unbalanced binary tree, unless you use a treap or other O(logn) datastructure.

The usual way of stashing a (complete) binary tree in an array, is to make node i have two children 2i and 2i+1.

Given this organization (not sorting but organization), you can go to a parent node from a leaf node by dividing the array index by 2 using integer arithmetic which will truncate fractions.

if your binary trees are not always complete, you'll probably be better served by forgetting about using an array, and instead using a more traditional tree structure with pointers/references.